# Query padding mask and key padding mask in Transformer encoder

Tags: python, pytorch, transformer-model, attention-model

I'm implementing self-attention part in transformer encoder using pytorch `nn.MultiheadAttention` and confusing in the padding masking of transformer.

The following picture shows the self-attention weight of the query (row) and key (column).

As you can see, there are some tokens "<PAD>" and I have already mask it in key. Therefore the tokens will not calculate the attention weight.

[image]

There are still two questions:

1. In query part, can I also mask them("<PAD>") except for the red square part? Is this reasonable?
2. How can I mask "<PAD>" in the query?

The attention weights also use the `softmax` function along the row by giving mask in `src_mask` or `src_key_padding_mask` argument. If I set all the "<PAD>" row into `-inf`, the `softmax` will return `nan` and the loss with be `nan`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to mask the queries during self-attention, it should be enough if do not use the states corresponding to the `<PAD>` tokens later in the network (either as hidden states or keys/values), they will not influence the loss function nor anything else in the network.

If you want to make sure that you did not make a bug causing the gradient flowing through the `<PAD>` tokens you can explicitly zero-out the self-attention using [`torch.where`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.where.html) after it is computed.

Comment: sorry, I can't understand why that's no need to mask the queries during self-attention. because I got bad performance in my task. So, I'm considering the where is the problem.

Comment: About gradient flowing, I'm really sure if I set `-inf` to all row6 ~ row13 it will return nan, because the attention weight pass the softmax function along each row. According to the pytorch source code  https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/778006918c31c3fa0ca3794575a65c1f854f861b/torch/nn/functional.py#L4297

Comment: You can do the `torch.where` _after_ the softmax and set the weights to zero.